# How can i delete/drop entire keyspace using php: cassandra :thrift

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift

How can i delete/drop entire keyspace using php: cassandra :thrift

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/LiveSchemaUpdates

Comment: I had tried to do the same from console mode, its throwing me the error 
steps i had followed
bin/cassandra-cli 
cassandra> delkeyspacename 

it is throwing the rror like
line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting DOT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeDelete(CliClient.java:201)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStmt(CliClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processCLIStmt(CliMain.java:213)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:270)